# label focus color and label focus visibility in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

There is any way to define **label focus color and visibility** in flex 4.5 and how to set label border color.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "label focus" and "label border"? I don't use Flex (only AS3), but due to there being no answers and comments I'm assuming these aren't common terms, even in Flex. Maybe a picture would help?

Comment: here label is simple text display component in flex or as3. use for display text. by default when mouse over on label it does not visible focus. i want to that when mouse over label a visible focus display on it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "visible focus". Do you want it to display a border when the mouse is over it?

Comment: yes,display border may also help for me.so please suggest your answer.